# How to handle LINQ to SQL Exceptions?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

Hi I'm implementing a local database inside of my WP7 app and was wondering how to handle different types of SqlCeExceptions that could arise when an operation is run on the database. For example I would want to show a certain error message if an attempt to delete an item bound by a foreign key was executed and a different error for lets say a random unhandled exception.

To me it would seem that maybe the Exception could be passed in a switch statment inside the catch block like so:

```
switch(myException)
{
   case ForeignKeyException:
      //Handle it this way...
      break;
   case UnhandledException:
      //Handle it another way...
      break;
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement this or maybe point me somewhere where I can learn how to handle these exceptions seperately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I do not have the answer, I have always solved this by never letting exceptions happen. I always check *before* inserting that the data is valid. I make sure that all unique indexes are respected (user name, ...) and that all foreign key problems have been dealt with. This is, IMHO, the only sane way to do this. I would not like producing exceptions and handling them because I could never be really sure that I do not catch *too many* exceptions and thereby hiding real bugs.

Comment: +1 I think you made an excellent point. Now that I went back, it is alot better to implement a form of checking rather than relying on exceptions. I went ahead and implemented what you said and it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    // something
}
catch(ForeignKeyException ex)
{
    // handle foreignkeyexception
}
catch(UnhandledException ex)
{
    // handle unhandledexception
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can distinguish between the different errors? I looked up the SqlCeException but I couldn't find a list of exceptions that I can check against. ForeignKeyException was peusdo code I wrote to explain my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a different catch block for each exception type that you care about?

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(a ae)
{
  ...
}
catch(b ab) ......
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like SqlCeException class has a `NativeError` property that you could switch on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceexception.aspx

```
catch (SqlCeException e)
{
    // Use SqlCeException properties if you need specific
    // application logic depending on the error condition
    //
    if (25046 == e.NativeError /*SSCE_M_FILENOTFOUND*/)
    {
        // Error specific logic goes here...
        //
    }
}
```